# Authorization fails (cookes not sent) in URLSessionConfiguration.background with HTTPCookieStorage.shared

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

In my iOS app, I create a URLSession with default configuration:

```
// Part #1    
let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
```

The user logs in, **the cookies are set** and all API requests are **Authorized** and work fine. Now with the same cookies, I want to create a background URLSession for downloading large files from the same server.

```
// Part #2 
lazy var downloadsSession: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:"x.bgSession")
        // Use cookies from shared storage
        configuration.httpCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
        return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()
```

The download request fails and the server returns **Unauthorized**. Using [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) when I intercept this request, I notice that for **downloadsSession**, **cookies are not set** while making the HTTP download request.

However, now when I create a new **ephemeral** session, the **Authorization** works fine.

```
// Part #3
let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        sessionConfiguration.httpCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
        session_ = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil);
```

What is the difference between Part #2 & Part #3 in terms of Authorization (setting cookies)? Why Part #3 succeeds while Part #2 fails?

Answer (score 0):

for your part  #1, #2, #3 
add following line to request

```
request.httpShouldHandleCookies=true
```

If it still give you the same error consult your backend developer and check download permissions for file your trying to download

for complete help you may  check following code

```
        let mainUrl = "your request url"
    request.httpMethod = serviceType
    request.httpShouldHandleCookies=true
    let cookie = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: mainUrl as URL)!)
    request = setAccessToken_Cookie(request: request)
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields  = cookie
    var  session  = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    session = NetworkManager().configureURLSessionMethodWithDelegate(session: session)
    if downloadable
    {
        Downloader.downloadFile(url: mainUrl as URL, session: session, request:request, completion:  {
        })
    }





import Foundation
import UIKit

class Downloader:NSObject, URLSessionDownloadDelegate
{
    class func downloadFile(url: URL,session:URLSession, request:NSMutableURLRequest, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        var delegateSession = Downloader().configureURLSessionMethodDelegate(session: session)
        let downloads = delegateSession.downloadTask(with: request as URLRequest)
        downloads.resume()
    }
    func configureURLSessionMethodDelegate( session:URLSession) -> URLSession {
        var sessionWithDelegate = session
        sessionWithDelegate = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)
        return sessionWithDelegate
    }
     func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        guard let httpResponse = downloadTask.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                  print ("error : \(error according to your response code)")
                return
        }
        do {
            let documentsURL = try
                FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                        in: .userDomainMask,
                                        appropriateFor: nil,
                                        create: false)
            let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename ?? "noname")
            print(location)
            print(savedURL)
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: savedURL.path)
            {
                AppUtility?.displayAlert(title: appName, messageText: "A file with same name already exist", delegate: nil)
            }
            else{
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: savedURL)
            }
        } catch {
            print ("file error: \(error)")
        }
    }
     func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
    {
        guard let httpResponse = downloadTask.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                print ("server error")
                return
        }
    }
     func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {  () -> Void in
            if(error != nil)
            {
                //handle the error
                print("Download completed with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work, did you try the code yourself? I am the backend developer as well. Problem is the cookies are not set by the front end.

Comment: i am already working  with ssl and cookies and my code works perfectly fine :)

Comment: show formation of your complete request if you can :) you may replace key pairs or header names with examplesheadernames

Comment: task = downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: item.remoteURL);
task?.resume()

Comment: you are setting cookies in sessionConfiguration?